Double values for triangle angles returning as NaN if 2+ side lengths are the same
I'm trying to write a program that will calculate the angles of a triangle using the side lengths (via the Law of Cosines, Law of Sines, and Triangle Sum Theorem). It works just fine if all the side lengths are different (i.e. scalene), but if two or more sides are the same (i.e. an isosceles or equilateral) all the values return as NaN. For example, a = 3, b = 4, c = 5 works fine; a = 5, b = 10, c = 10 OR a = 5, b = 5, c = 5 do NOT work and the angle values return as NaN. Could anyone help me from here?
public class Triangle
{
    private double sidea, sideb, sidec;
    private double angleA, angleB, angleC;

    public Triangle()       //input-based constructor
    {
        setSideA();
        setSideB();
        setSideC();
        angleA = 0;
        angleB = 0;
        angleC = 0;
    }

    public void setSideA()      //sets side lengths
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter length of Side A: ");
        sidea = scan.nextDouble();
    }
    public void setSideB()
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter length of Side B: ");
        sideb = scan.nextDouble();
    }
    public void setSideC()
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter length of Side C: ");
        sidec = scan.nextDouble();
    }

    public void calcAngleC()        //calculates angles in order of C, B, A
    {
        angleC = Math.acos((Math.pow(sidea,2) + Math.pow(sideb,2) - Math.pow(sidec,2)) / 2 * sidea * sideb);
    }
    public void calcAngleB()
    {
        angleB = Math.asin((sideb * Math.sin(angleC)) / sidec);
    }
    public void calcAngleA()        //already in degrees
    {
        angleA = 180 - Math.toDegrees(angleB) - Math.toDegrees(angleC);
    }
    
    public void printStats()
    {
        System.out.printf("\nSide A: %1.2f", sidea);
        System.out.printf("\nSide B: %1.2f", sideb);
        System.out.printf("\nSide C: %1.2f", sidec);
        System.out.printf("\n\nAngle A: %1.2f%1s", angleA, (char)176);
        System.out.printf("\nAngle B: %1.2f%1s", Math.toDegrees(angleB), (char)176);
        System.out.printf("\nAngle C: %1.2f%1s", Math.toDegrees(angleC), (char)176);
    }
}

Sorry if this is too much code, this is my first time posting here.

Welcome to Stack Exchange. One minor point first pow(x,2) is less accurate and much slower than the simpler calculation x*x. I think your formula for angleC is wrong - the denominator should be in brackets / (2* sidea * sideb). You should also defend against the annoying possibility that rounding errors lead to a value for the argument handed to acos() that is machine_eps or so outside the valid range |C| <= 1.0. That will also lead to a Nan. If paranoid then protect every division where the divisor could be zero as well. Bad data in error messages out is a very good maxim.

@MartinBrown Thank you so much! You're right, the denominator error was such a silly mistake. But I didn't know that pow(x,2) was slower and less accurate than a simple x*x, so thank you so much!
